# Passing a parameter via stack to procedure in MASM

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I am trying to pass 3 parameters to a procedure, add them, and return them in tax register in MASM. However, the result is off with a random huge number. I am trying to use the C style calling convention where I am passing 3 variables to a function. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
INCLUDE PCMAC.INC


.MODEL SMALL
.586
.STACK 100h
.DATA

.CODE
        EXTRN  GetDec :NEAR, PutDDec : NEAR, PutHex : NEAR
Main PROC
        _Begin
        push 10
        push 20
        push 30

        call Test1


        call PutDDec
        add esp, 12

        _Exit
Main ENDP
Test1 PROC
    ; *** Standard subroutine prologue ***
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 4
    push edi
    push esi

    ; *** Subroutine Body ***

    mov eax, [ebp+8] ; parameter 1 / character
    mov esi, [ebp+12] ; parameter 2 / width
    mov edi, [ebp+16] ; parameter 3 / height

    mov [ebp-4], edi
    add [ebp-4], esi
    add eax, [ebp-8]
    add eax, [ebp-4]

    ; *** Standard subroutine epilogue ***
    pop esi ; Recover register values
    pop edi
    mov esp, ebp ; Deallocate local variables
    pop ebp ; Restore the caller’s base pointer value

    ret
Test1 ENDP
End Main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You did not comment your code and you did not use a debugger.

```
mov [ebp-4], edi
add [ebp-4], esi
add eax, [ebp-8] ; <---- what is this ebp-8 here?
add eax, [ebp-4]
```

To add 3 numbers you only need 2 additions, why do you have 3?
Also you don't even need to use a local variable, you can just do:

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

mov eax, [ebp+8] ; parameter 1 / character
add eax, [ebp+12] ; parameter 2 / width
add eax, [ebp+16] ; parameter 3 / height

mov esp, ebp ; Deallocate local variables
pop ebp ; Restore the caller’s base pointer value

ret
```

Or, if you don't need the stack frame then just:

```
mov eax, [esp+4]
add eax, [esp+8]
add eax, [esp+12]
ret
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I call "call PutDDec", the result is not the addition. Do you know the reason for this? Thanks

Comment: We don't know how `PutDDec` expects the argument, maybe it wants that on the stack too. Adding `mov [esp], eax` before `call PutDDec` could be worth a try.

Comment: PutDDec prints out the decimal version of EAX register

Comment: Well, what gets printed?

Comment: `781106505` I am following   `mov eax, [esp+4]
add eax, [esp+8]
add eax, [esp+12]
ret ` as my function

Answer (score 0):

In your *subroutine body*, the sum of the three parameters could be done like this:

```
mov [ebp-4], edi   ;Move EDI into your local var
add [ebp-4], esi   ;Add ESI into your local var
add eax, [ebp-4]   ;Finally, add the contents of your local var into EAX
                   ;(note that EAX contains first param)
```

Your mistake was on `[ebp-8]`.

Also as Jester noted in his more thorough answer, you dont really need a local var to do the sum.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the program to work by using the ax part of the base pointer, since I was pushing 2 DB, not DW:

```
INCLUDE PCMAC.INC


.MODEL SMALL
.586
.STACK 100h
.DATA
sum DWORD ?

.CODE
        EXTRN  GetDec :NEAR, PutDec : NEAR, PutHex : NEAR
Main PROC
        _Begin
        push 10
        push 20

        call Test12
        ;and eax, 0ffffh

        call PutDec

        _Exit
Main ENDP
Test12 PROC
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov ax, [bp+6] ;
    add ax, [bp+4] ;

    pop bp
    ret 4
Test12 ENDP
End Main
```